# Actualizar mediante ajax y javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Tengo las siguientes opciones, la cuales deben de actualizar dos sw diferentes:

en la primera tengo las opciones de `ninguna, aut, y hab` y en la segunda tengo la opción de `sw_visible`, la cual es `1` o `0` dependientes si es activa o inactiva.

```
<td align=\"center\" >;
<select id='resolucion' name='resolucion' onchange='c_resolucion()'>;
<option value=''>NINGUNO</option>;
<option value='AUT'>AUT</option>;
<option value='HAB'>HAB</option>;
</select>";

<td align=\"center\" >";
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"sw_visible\" value=\"1\"  onclick=\"c_resolucion()\">Si";
</td>";
```

quiero que ambos utilicen la misma funcion javascrips. y que me actualice la opción dependiendo de lo que el cliente utilice en el formulario.

esta es la siguiente funcion

```
function c_resolucion(resolucion)
{
            var resolucion, cajas; 
      resolucion = document.getElementById('resolucion');  
     // document.form1.orden.value = ''

      resolucion = document.form1.resolucion.options[document.form1.resolucion.selectedIndex].value

      ajax=nuevoAjax(); 

      ajax.open('POST','ajax_resolucion.php',true); 

      ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
      { 
        if (ajax.readyState==4) { 

           resolucion.innerHTML = ajax.responseText 


        } 

      }

            ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Connection','Close');
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache, must-revalidate');
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Expires','Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            ajax.send('&resolucion='+resolucion+'&sw_visible='+sw_visible);

}
</script>";
```

y este el archivo ajax el cual realiza la actualización.

```
$d_resolucion=$_POST['resolucion'];


?>
<td>
<?php
 $sql = "UPDATE m_puntos_pago set d_resolucion='"$d_resolucion"' WHERE caja = ".$caja;

 $sql_status_in=gp_execute2($sql);

    ?>
```

como realiza el update dependiendo de la opcion que el cliente realice.
ya se precionar el check o seleccionar algunas de las opciones del campo de_resolucion.

Comment: He leído la pregunta tres veces y aún no entiendo qué es lo que dice o qué es lo que se intenta hacer. De hecho, no hay pregunta por ningún sitio. Por favor, añade información adicional como qué es lo que se quiere hacer, con qué problemas te encuentras, o qué errores estás recibiendo (si recibes alguno)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la pregunta es como enviar el update al archivo ajax,  dependiendo de la opción que utilice el usuario en el formulario, ejemplo si chulea la opción de si en el cambio sw_visible, solo me actualice ese campo y si seleccione alguna opcion de la lista de auto, hab tambien haga el update solo de esa seleccion. pero todo en el mismo archivo.

Comment: Intenta ser lo más __profesionalmente__ posible, evita por ejemplo términos como "chulea la opción" para que todos podamos entender que quieres decir y poder ayudarte con tu problema

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la pregunta es como enviar el update al archivo ajax, dependiendo de la opción que utilice el usuario en el formulario, ejemplo si presionan la opción de si en el campo sw_visible, solo me actualice ese campo y si seleccione alguna opcion de la lista de auto, hab y ninguno, tambien haga el update solo de esa seleccion.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que entendí, solo necesitas saber de donde esta siendo llamada la función para poder actualizar el elemento que le corresponde. Solo coloca un id en el input así como al select y pasa por parámetro this.

Por ejemplo:

```
<input id="myinput" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"sw_visible\" value=\"1\" onclick=\"c_resolucion(this)\">Si";
//Javascript
function c_resolucion ( argumentos ){
   console.log( argumentos )
   //Accedes al id y luego evalúas de donde fue llamada y que deseas activar
}
```